# ggplot 2 does not display the correct value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having a hard time to plot this in the right way:

```
data.frame':181 obs. of  3 variables:
Profissão: Factor w/ 2 levels "Médico","Enfermeiro": 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 1 ... 
social: num  25 32 34 29 29 40 38 31 33 35 ...
Servico: Factor w/ 2 levels "HMPB","HMU": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...



Profissão social Servico
1 Médico     25     HMU
2 Médico     32     HMU
3 Médico     34     HMU
4 Médico     29     HMU
5 Enfermeiro 29     HMU
6 Médico     40     HMU

 mean(df$social[df$Profissão=="Médico" & df$Servico=="HMPB"])
30.68421
 mean(df$social[df$Profissão=="Médico" & df$Servico=="HMU"])
28.83333

ggplot(df, aes(Profissão, social)) + 
geom_bar(aes(fill = factor(Servico)), stat="identity", position = "dodge")
```

But ggplot is resulting this:

[image]

image is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/f0t5q3ll9m2ez6x/ggplot2.PNG?dl=0

Comment: You have multiple values of `social` for each `Profissao`-`Servicio` combination instead of a single value to plot.  What are you trying to display?  Maybe means or sums?

Comment: means. .. thanks for helping :)

Comment: Thanks much. I was trying to find someone with the same question ...

After 6 hours googling, now is ok
Thanks much!!!

My code now is this one:
  df <- sheila[c("Profissão","social","Servico")]
    ggplot(df, aes(x = Profissão, y = social, fill = Servico)) + 
    geom_bar(aes(Profissão, social, fill = as.factor(Servico)), 
             position = "dodge", stat = "summary", fun.y = "mean")

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping. If someone wants to check out the code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Profissão, y = social, fill = Servico)) + 
geom_bar(aes(Profissão, social, fill = as.factor(Servico)), 
         position = "dodge", stat = "summary", fun.y = "mean")
```